# Agoritmo del factorial iterativo

Tags: recursión

Saludos para todos y gracias desde ya
Analizando este algoritmo no encuentro explicacion al funcionamiento como tal de la recursividad
en este caso, al final me da el resultado pero no entiendo el funcionamiento de la recursividad en este algoritmo no sé si alguien tiene esta explicación

```
var factorial = function(n) {
    // base case: 
    if(n === 0){
    return 1;
    
    }
    else{
    // recursive case:
    return factorial(n-1) * n; 

}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

La clave de la recursividad,está en el condicional que tienes,

Ya que este define si se va a realizar un nuevo llamado a la funcion o va a dar un retorno final.

Voy a tratar de explicar con palabras lo que hace la recursividad, espero ser claro.

Al ejecutar la funcion y agregar el parámetro, si el parámetro que recibe es cero, lo que va a realizar internamente es un llamado a si mismo. Esto se repetírá hasta que se cumpla la condición, de que n sea cero, para esto, lo que se hace es que n vaya reduciendo su valor, si no se hace esto, nunca va a finalizar el llamado a si mismo. El hecho es que cada factorial valida el valor de n - 1. Entonces esto ayuda a que en algún punto en el if del condicional se cumpla que sea cero y logre llegar al retorno definitivo.

```
factorial
  → factorial
      → factorial
          → 0;
```

Basicamente lo que vemos arriba es lo que ocurrirá, cada que se llame a la funcion factorial y esta entre al else, el retorno que de el ultimo llamado a la funcion factorial se pasará al proceso que le llamó, es decir al factorial anterior hasta llegar a la ejecución principal. De esta manera finalizará la ejecución de todos los llamados realizados sobre si mismo.

Tener en cuenta que este proceso debe analizarse muy bien, ya que al no saber hacer que el proceso entre a la condicional if, podría generarse un bucle infinito. es como si se hciera un while(true).

Saludos.